Relation between thermal expansion coefficient and Poisson ratio
Is there any relation between the thermal expansion coefficient $\alpha$ and Poisson ratio $\nu$ of a material?

There's no general link, no. The thermal expansion coefficient is $\alpha\equiv\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P$; the Poisson ratio is $\nu\equiv-\frac{\varepsilon_\mathrm{lateral}}{\varepsilon_\mathrm{axial}}$ (volume $V$, temperature $T$, pressure $P$, strain $\varepsilon$). Various compounds and alloys have thermal expansion coefficients that are negative, positive, or zero while still having a positive Poisson ratio; various structures and metamaterials have Poisson ratios that are negative, positive, or zero while still having a positive thermal expansion coefficient, for example.
